# How do I fix a leak under a bathroom sink?

Tags: bathroom, sink

[image]The leak is happening where the red circle is, and started after I flushed the drain with clog remover. Based on other plumbing pictures I found, the pipes look like they may not even be the right type. Is this something I can fix myself? [image]

Comment: Looks like it might not be glued together. Can you verify?

Comment: It’s not glued.

Comment: Please add a picture with a wider view of all the pipe work from the sink to the wall.  Press "Edit" above and add another picture just as you did before.  This will allow people to make more specific recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion. I added another photo for better perspective and detail.

Comment: Well if it's not glued, you should expect it to leak!

Answer (score 2):

From what can be seen in the initial picture (one that shows more would be helpful) this is a hack job that violates code.

You could (probably, we can't see much of it) turn it into a hack job that meets code by gluing the joints in the PVC, but there's a non-hack approach to turn it into a reasonable, serviceable, trap assembly for an accessible under-sink location.

Go buy a nice new polypropylene plastic trap that has the same sort of fittings you see on the top of your picture, and a slim tube output that goes into one of those fittings. Yank your code-violating unglued PVC trap out of there, but save the trap adapter on top of the picture, and glue that to the wall pipe, after making sure the wall pipe is glued in at the wall connection. Assemble your new polypropylene slip-fitting plastic trap to slip onto your sink tailpiece, and slip into the newly glued in the right place trap adapter - then tighten the nuts on the slip fittings.

[image: Slip-fit plastic trap image from hardwarestore.com]

Most people first meeting one of these do not realize that the end which slips in is provided long, so it can be trimmed to fit. There is a range of adjustment, (visible on the vertical entry as a wide section several inches long) but don't cut too short, too fast, or you have to go buy another one if you cut off too much. Also realize that the joint in the middle of the trap can rotate to make things fit, as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I added a larger photo for better perspective, but based on everything we’ve encountered in this house, it wouldn’t surprise me to find this plumbing was done wrong.

Comment: Depending what's glued and what you want to do, you could reasonably fix this via gluing, since it's a union-type trap, so the bend is removable by undoing the union nuts in the middle of the trap and the slip joint where the sink tailpiece enters. All the PVC-to-PVC joints need to be properly solvent welded with the correct cement. Personally, I prefer the slip-joint type trap, as it retains adjustability. One problem with a dry-fit trap is that it may not fit right when welded, as the pipes go a bit further in than they do dry.

Comment: I suspect the OP would have difficulty adapting the pictured P-trap, due to the apparent size of the pipe at the wall.

Comment: @Huesmann Diameter-wise, we see that the pipe at the wall is the same size as the pipe at the trap inlet, which is bigger than the trap adapter. Length-wise, see last paragrapgh of the answer.

Comment: @Ecnerwal what part of code do you figure this violates (other than not being glued up)?

Comment: Being glued up is part of code. No need for an other part. Gluing glue-joint type drain pipe is not optional.